# batch resizing for image with different aspect ratio to be of same dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

My question is about batch resizing, now i followed this tutorial **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MRBCuUAzwg)** .

Now i had some some images in a folder which were of dimensions of 5000+ pixels , i need these images for the web , so the image s should be about 1200*700 exactly(VERY IMPORTANT AND THATS exactly what my question is about) , now when i batch resize and the new images are saved in a new file , i get dimensions of .

```
1050*700
933*700
```

(i see that the aspect ratio is maintained ... but what i really wanted was 1200*700px)

much better !

now i have a idea , i have a plan white template on 1200*700, is there a automated action in photoshop which i can use to copy these new resized images and past on this white template and than save each image , so that i get all images to be 1200*700 ?? (This approach i know is a bit dirty and not ideal for all use cases , but its perfect for me ! ). Is this possible , if so , it would be a life saver .

Thank you.

Comment: What you are asking will require cropping to the same aspect ratio and then resizing. Who will decide on how to crop, you or the action?

Answer (score 1):

This should be very simple:

Record a new action batch, and in that set canvas size to 1200px width (making sure matte is white), save image.

You have already got all of your images to 700px height, so,
Now run this on your selected folder and hey presto all images will be changed to 1200x700, and either cropped width if is used to be bore than 1200px wide or with a white stripe down each side if it used to be less than 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some exacting reason to use Photoshop, I would suggest you use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) instead. It is much more productive to work in shell application when you batch big amount of pictures.

- Relevant examples for scaling [here in the docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)

Because the application is free its also easy to use this automation wherever you need it, including your server application. Its also potentially significantly faster than PS.